# Can translator microbes work on animals?

Tags: farscape

The microbes seem to let various species understand the spoken language of many other species. One noted exception is the full language of the Pilot.

Anyway, when Crichton returns to Earth, would he be able to understand the language of animals such as dolphins or whales? Where's the line in the ability to translate?

Comment: Dolphins and whales don't have language. They have signature whistles and alarm/food calls, but there's no grammar or syntax or vocabulary.

Comment: Nice, good question.

Comment: Before discounting whales as having no language, you might want to do a bit more research. While a lot of it isn't conclusive, much of it implies there is the potential for language structures and we are simply unclear on how it is configured or what information is being transmitted. Perhaps we should say these intelligent animals are speaking a language WE DON'T KNOW YET. [Warbling Whales Have a Language All Their Own](http://www.hhmi.org/news/warbling-whales-speak-language-all-their-own)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the episode [Beware of Dog](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Beware_of_Dog), Chiana brings a small creature on board. Eventually they need to use it to hunt down a parasite, and in order to better communicate with it they inject it with translator microbes. While John and Aeryn can't understand it, Pilot can. It doesn't have all of the concepts in its language as the rest of the crew does, but the translator microbes did help to communicate with it and find the parasite.

To answer your question, I would guess that injecting an animal with translator microbes would be similar - Pilot could likely understand what the animal is saying, given the limitation that the animal can only express certain concepts in its "language".

Comment: I just reviewed that episode. The translator microbes given to the Vorc do not help anyone, including Pilot, understand the Vorc but allow the Vorc to understand everyone else. Pilot states that he can mostly understand the Vorc through his connection with Moya, not because the Vorc was given translator microbes. So it may be possible for Pilot to understands dolphins and whales. And since Crichton or Aeryn couldn't understand the Vorc, it would seem that Crichton would not be able to understand dolphins or whales either since they don't have real language either.

Comment: So while your answer is sort of backwards, the "Beware of Dog" episode sets a good precedent to answer my original question. And that answer seems to be no, in won't work on animals that don't have a real language.

Comment: It had been a while since I saw the episode, so I probably remembered the details incorrectly. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem. It led me to the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

They did run a whole slew of different language speaking people in front of Crichton to 'interpret', but no animals. I would say yes it could translate the language if the language was sufficiently developed/structured. Deliberate clicks, grunts, growls, tonal and volume changes etc. that are designed to communicate would be in fact translatable. If humans without such tech can reliably and consistently interpret different animal species' audible communication then yes the translator microbes could interpret that 'language'. If they weren't understandable, how could others of their species understand?

Comment: This seems valid. And given that whales and dolphins does (as far as we know) have a "proper" language, it would seem that the answer to my question is no.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it was more than that too, pilot understands more because biologically he is able to process more, telepathy, empathy, and body language don't use any syntax in their natural expression, however I bet that someone using the TM would have an easier time understanding what the smarter creatures wanted, what they were trying to communicate, but it it would be dependent on the awareness of the one trying, also I'm not sure Pilot actually has the Translator Microbes or if his species is just that smart.